# Opencv using imread and vector of QString filenames to load images

Tags: qt, opencv, c++11, qstring

I have been trying to read some images in a loop using `imread` into a vector of `Mat` (images) with opencv by getting the filenames from a vector of `QString` but it will not compile. I know it's the format of my `QString` that's the problem but cannot seem to work it out. I have also tried ...`image = imread( image_vector[i] );`... and several other ways. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < image_names.size(); i++ )
{ 
    image = imread( image_names.data()->at(i) );

    if( !image.data )
    {
        qDebug()<< "Error";
    }
    else
    {
         image_vector.push_back( image );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `image_vector`? You seem to be both reading the filenames from it as well as adding cv matrices to it?

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong names, I have edited.

Comment: try something like `image_names[i].toStdString().c_str()`.

Comment: if that's really a compile error, why don't you post the compiler error message?

Comment: The declaration of imread is: `CV_EXPORTS_W Mat imread( const string& filename, int flags=1 );` so, if `image_names` is an array or vector of QString, you should use: `image = imread( image_names[i].toStdString() );`

Comment: Sure, the compile error is: `invalid initialization of reference of type 'const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}' from expression of type 'const QChar' image = imread( image_names.data()->at(i) );`

Comment: Which is the definition of `image_names`? Is it a QVector or a QString (in this case `image_names.data()` return a QChar * pointer and `image_names.data()->at(i)` return a QChar)?

Comment: It's declared as `vector <QString> image_names`.

Comment: Right: `image_names.data()` returns a QString * pointer and `image_names.data()->at(i)` returns the ith QChar of the first QString of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using `imread` you have to pass a `std::string` to it .

```
Mat imread( const std::string& filename, int flags=1 );
```

In your case `image_names` is `vector<QString>` so the correct code is :

```
image = imread( image_names[i].toStdString());
```